# What to know before installing cabinet and drawer dampers?

Tags: doors, kitchens

I want to install dampers on my new cabinet doors in my kitchen. When the contractor gave me the price to add these, the cost was over $30 per door. So I decided not to install them. But since then, I have found these dampers on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003COGL7M) and the price is under $3 each.

What do I need to know before investing in these dampers? At $3 each, is it worth it or not? Are they easy to install on cabinet (both drawer and door)?

Comment: yea - the difference is that the contractor was not going to use these dampers.. but the built in to the mechanism which are ALLOT MORE BETTER- best thing is to change your mechanism and pay a bit more- seel your old ones.. those dampers of amazon break..

Comment: THIS  http://www.woodstockco.com/why_calypso.php  AND THIS http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cupboard+soft+close+mechanism&hl=en&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&ei=0KogTrSQA4yx8QOIzeXBAw&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=1&ved=0CC4Q_AUoAA&biw=1280&bih=675#hl=en&pq=cupboard%20soft%20close%20mechanism&xhr=t&q=soft+close+hinges&cp=12&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=soft+close+h&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=46c8377fe9b7fe43&biw=1280&bih=675   ESPECIALLY THESE http://www.softclosehinges.co.uk/

Comment: Alright, so your opinion is to not touch those? How come they break if they are handled by adult?

Comment: They waer out much faster - over time you might need to replace some.. and it carries on. better to buy quality and have peace of mind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The door dampers you link to look very similar to the ones I have installed in my kitchen.

They are very easy to install - they just screw to the cabinet as shown. In fact [this item](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0036B4NTY) shows it even more clearly.

They work very well and I don't see why you should pay any more.

Comment: do you have a brand you could recommend, have had good experience with?

Comment: @Mike - they were [Wickes](http://www.wickes.co.uk/) own brand.

Comment: I may give a try soon to check on some drawers and cabinets. Thx for your input.

Comment: @ChrisF have you put them on your drawers also?

Comment: @Daok - no, as the units we bought came with damping runners. I haven't tried these on drawers - I'm not sure they'd fit to be perfectly honest.